# how i can solve this error thread with bool method in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services

this code in my Windows service project  give me Compile error
**Expected a method with void InitializeBridge signature**

```
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
            if (args != null && args.Length == 1 && args[0].StartsWith("-c"))
            {
                 BridgeService bridgeService = new BridgeService();

                 if (Vytru.Platform.Bridge.Configuration.LicenseValidetor.ValidCountAndTypeDevices())
                 {
                      Console.WriteLine("Bridge Service Is Started ......");

                      var daemonThread = new Thread(SharedData.InitializeBridge);
                      daemonThread.Start();
                 }
                 else
                 {
                      Console.WriteLine("Bridge Service License is not Valid ...");
                 }
            }
            else
            {
                 ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
                 ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
                  { 
                      new BridgeService() 
                  };
                 ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
            }
      }
```

and this is my static method `InitializeBridge`..

```
      public static bool InitializeBridge()
      {
            return DeviceList.All(CreateBridgeConnection);

      }
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 2):

You can't create a `ThreadStart` or `ParameterizedThreadStart` from a method which returns `bool`, basically. Those are the two delegate types which can be passed to the `Thread` constructor, and there's no applicable method group conversion here.

If you don't care about the return value (which seems odd to start with) the simplest approach is probably to use a lambda expression to call it and ignore the return value:

```
var daemonThread = new Thread(() => SharedData.InitializeBridge());
```